# Javascript - getting keydown in a loop

Tags: javascript, events, browser, keydown, createjs

I am trying to make a browser game (using createjs, if this makes a difference) and the problem I'm trying to figure out is how do I get the event `keydown` in a loop, and no sudden.

For example,

```
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function() {

    // here
    if (isUpArrowKeyPressed) {
        movePlayerUp(); // This is an example, ignore this
    }

});
```

So this way, if the key is pressed for exactly 1 second it would do what is inside it 60 times. (60fps)

Any way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717091/easeljs-keyboard-ticker-problems.  This should move you in the right direction (no pun intended)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828613/check-if-a-key-is-down

Comment: thanks guys, you rock. what should I do with the question, delete it?

Comment: If you work out a nice answer, you can answer it yourself, it may help other people in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to pass in the event parameter to your function. From there you'll be able to see which key was pressed

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   var keyCode = e.keyCode

   // Compare the keycode
   if (keyCode === 57) {
       movePlayerUp(); // This is an example, ignore this
   }

});
```

Comment: This is a new one! cool and thanks to not make this question useless :)